# React com TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react

Olá, estou aprendendo  a fazer aplicações React com TS, e dentro dos meus estudos me deparei com um problema.

Estou exportando um componente da seguinte forma

```
const Button = styled.button`
background-color: Transparent;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: none;
cursor:pointer;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 2px;
float: right;
color: white;

`

export const RaisedButton = (props:IProps) => <Button>{props.label}</Button>

interface IProps {
label: string
}
```

Quando importo RaisedButton na minha index, ela entra como a classe button e o botão se atribui somente as propriedades .css definidas a cima.

Gostaria de saber se é possivel atribuir multiplas propriedades .css dentro do mesmo componente Button, assim, exporto varias propriedades e não preciso recriar o componente, somente as propriedades.

Comment: você quer então aplicar estilos diferentes em determinada importação do seu componente button? é isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é bem isso que você deseja, mas você pode passar os atributos padrão de um botão para o componente filho da seguinte maneira:

```
 const Button = styled.button<BtnProps>`
      height: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      color: white;
    `;
    
   interface MyButtonProps {
      label?: string;
    }
    
   type CustomButtonProps = MyButtonProps &
      React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
    
   export const CustomButton = (props: CustomButtonProps) => {
       const {label, ...defaultButtonProps} = props
       
       return <Button {...defaultButtonProps}>{props.label}</Button>;
    };
```